# highlight a line word by word with a specific time

Tags: jquery

I have a line like this: `the world is so big`

I want to know how to highlight this line word by word by a timer with jQuery(for example highlight must finish in 20 sec).
 I searched a lot Google and forums but i could not find a good way.

Comment: exactly i want to highlight a line slowly from start to end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution : http://jsfiddle.net/fCWXL/

**HTML :**

```
<span id=sentence><span class=tok>The</span> <span class=tok>word</span> <span class=tok>is</span> <span class=tok>too</span> <span class=tok>big</span></span>​
```

**javascript :**

```
var tokens = $('#sentence').find('.tok');
var n = tokens.length;
var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    tokens.css('background-color', 'white');
    $('#sentence').find('.tok:eq('+(index%n)+')').css('background-color', 'red');
    index++;
}, 20000/n);
```

The idea is simply to, every 20000/n millisecondes, change the background of the next token.     ​
Of course you'd have to tune it for the exact desired effect.

Comment: Nice solution; fundamentally the entirety of the `setInterval` callback could quite elegantly be compressed to a single line... good bless jQuery.

`tokens.css('background-color', 'white').eq(index++ % n).css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: Yes. And it's also possible and easy to let the script tokenize the sentence (depends on the need, I'd provide it if required).

Answer (score 1):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ipovul/6/edit)*

Having this:

```
<p class="word">the world is so big</p>
```

the idea was to let jQuery wrap each word into spans so you don't have to do it manually:

```
  $(this).contents().wrap('<span></span>');
  $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/ /ig,'</span> <span>') );
```

And create a setInterval to highlight (adding a class) each word in your paragraph. Here is the whole code:

```
$('p.word').each(function(){
  
  $(this).contents().wrap('<span></span>');
  $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/ /ig,'</span> <span>') );
  
  var span = $(this).find('span');
  var countSpans = span.length;
  var i = 0;
  var inter;
  
  function highlighting(){
    if(i<countSpans){
      span.removeClass('highlight').eq(i++).addClass('highlight'); 
    }else{
      clearInterval(inter);
      span.removeClass('highlight');
    }
  }
  inter = setInterval(highlighting, 8000/countSpans);
  
});
```